# Android: Transfer file over TCP Java Socket

Tags: java, php, android, sockets, file-io

I am currently trying to transfer a file from a Android device to a Java TCP Server, but I am unable to find a good example which explains the structure I would need to implement this. There are many Java Client&Server examples there which explain file transfer but I want to make sure if this will still work once one throws an Android Device in there.

My question is how do I implement this sort of structure? And if it doesn't work, would I be better sending the file over an HTTP connection to a PHP server? I see a lot of examples and documentation online for the later method so I presume it is more reliable. I would however prefer to use a Java server.

The file consists of a large set of coordinates recorded by the Android device which will then be sent to the server. I have not yet established how I will store this data yet but I was originally going to store them in a primitive text file.

Comment: Update: I found an example located here: http://lakjeewa.blogspot.co.uk/2012/03/simple-android-application-to-send-file.html

However I am still unsure if it would be better for me to use this java implementation or if I should instead create a PHP server.

Comment: What is special about your use case that does not make sense for uploading a character stream?

Comment: Thor: I will be storing the files for a long period of time on the server. I suppose I could send a character stream and then compose a file on the server, but I figured that this method seemed simpler.

Comment: Well, isn't that how file transfers work?

Comment: Depends on your protocol I would assume. Though to be honest, I dont know if there is much difference between sending a file stream or a character stream. I have a hard time thinking that low level :P

Comment: Sounds like a good time to learn how things work under the hood, then.

Comment: Nope, in this case the outcome of learning the difference does not nearly justify the time to research and test. Got better things to do :)

Comment: Like inventing your own protocols?  Interesting priority.  Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Design**

The first thing you need is something to allow you to run Java code on your server.

There are a number of options. Two of the most popular technologies are [Glassfish](http://glassfish.java.net/) and [Apache Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/).

Crudely speaking Apache Tomcat is sufficient for simple client-server communication and Glassfish is used if you need to do more complex stuff. Both allow [Servlets](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/tutorial/1_3-fcs/doc/Servlets2.html) (which are essentially self contained server classes written in Java) to run on the server-side.

They handle communication with the client by launching a JVM (Java Virtual Machine) each time they receive a request. The Java servlet can run inside the JVM and respond do some processing if required before sending a response back to the client.Each new request is run in a new instance of a servlet. This makes dealing with multiple concurrent requests simpler (no need for more complex threading).

[image: Rough application-server design]

**Networking (sending data to and from the server)**

In networking situations the client can be a PC, an Android phone, or any other device capable of connecting to the internet. As far as the server is concerned, if the client can communicate using HTTP (a standard protocol which it understands) the it doesn't care what sort of device it is. This means that solutions for PC desktop client-server applications are similar to one for a phone.

You can use library such as [Apache HTTP Components](http://hc.apache.org/) to make it easier to handle HTTP requests and responses between the device and the server. Of course you could write your own classes to do this using Sockets but this would be *very* time consuming, particularly if you have never done it before.

**Storage of Data**

If you have time I would recommend implementing some sort of database to store the information.
They have a number of benefits to such as data recovery mechanisms, indexing for fast searching of data, ensure data integrity, better structuring of data and so on.
If you decide to use a database I recommend [MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/). It is a free and more importantly - well documented.

Aside: [JDBC](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) can be used to communicate with the database with Java.

---

Sorry about the in-line hyperlinks - apparently my repuation isn't high enough to post more than two!

Source: Personal experience from implementing a similar design.

Comment: Hi Maurice, thank you for the input. An Apache server isn't something I had considered yet, I was just going to launch my Java server through Ant but as I will be running it on a VM an Apache server may be more suitable.

One question however: I will be using a MySQL database to store information, and a reference to the file with large amounts of data (ie. up to 300KB per file, per transfer). Is it possible for me to store this in MySQL? So far I have stored nothing in a MySQL table except a few longs and strings.

Comment: I'm not sure if you are asking whether MySQL is capable of storing that quantity of data or whether it would be a suitable solution for your data.

In the case of the former the database size is generally only limited by the available disk space on the server.

For the second scenario, it is possible to store a reference to a file as well as some data. The reference to the file could simply being a path to a raw file stored as a string in a table.
If the data is repeating (i.e. the attributes are the same, but different values) then a database is the way to go.
I hope this is a bit clearer.

Comment: Yes thanks Maurice. At the very least it gives me a more clear idea what I want to do for my implementation :)

Comment: Lastly, did you have an opinion on using HTTP transfer as opposed to my current method for android? I read somewhere that it is the more supported way of doing it.

Comment: If the solution that you linked to above would certainly be one way to do it. However, you would still need to handle that raw character stream on the server-side. This might be as simple as immediately writing it out to a text file.
Also as it is with sockets you would have no real way of knowing whether your data was received unless you send back an acknowledgement to your client application. If it were me I would still use HTTP as it offers so much more - resending of dropped packets, error handling, security, etc. However if these features are all superfluous then go ahead and use sockets.

Comment: Depending on the security surrounding your server a firewall may be in place which blocks incoming connections. Most firewall will allow HTTP, which operates on Port 80 and HTTPS (Port 443). In the example the port used is 4444, which may be unsupported.
Finally, don't use FTP, SFTP, or FTPS. While at first glance they seem perfect for file transfer the protocol is blocked by many ISPs.

Comment: Thanks again Maurice, think I will have a look at HTTP. I was going to just design my own protocol using sockets which would send an acknowledgement back to the client once it is done, but I may as well just use HTTP to save me the work.